# Hiding the modal div using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a site that uses jQuery UI and its modals. You can see the modals until the page loads (that is a second or two). I would like it to not be shown at all while the site loads. Is there a way to do this?

```
  <div id="dialog">
  <!-- some content here that is shown until the site finishes loading -->
  </div>
```

EDIT: To further clarify, the modals work perfectly but the content in the modals are shown as HTML until the site ends loading.

Comment: Did you tried with $('#dialog').hide()?

Comment: Or do you tried `$("#dialog").modal("hide");`?

Comment: have you tried to show the modal only after the page has loaded ? using a `$(window).on("load",function() {  ` ?

Comment: Move the js file containing the ui library before other scripts.. it could be that you are loading the ui script later than it should..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
style="display: none;"
```

to the dialog div.

EDIT:
When you would like to show the dialog after it is initialized and page is loaded call

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open")
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Adding what I suggested will hide the dialog content until the code will show it by calling $("#dialog").dialog("open").